# How do I kill zombies in Minecraft and not get hurt?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there a smart way of disposing zombies and not losing like 2-3-4-5 hearts in the process? No matter how far you are, they always seem to reach further than you can which sucks... :S zombies should be short range not snipers..

Ok, so is there a specific tactic that works? A specific timing to hit them and not get hit? (except bow and arrow..)

thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Another method is to use a lighter, and ignite the ground while running backwards. It is less risky (provided you're outside setting fire to grass, not inside your wooden house!).

The monsters run into the fire and ignite.

Comment: This method works, but is situational. You can accidentally set a forest or your own structures on fire if you are not careful. Provided with a flat open plain, however, it works reasonably well. In addition, the materials for a lighter are a little harder to come by than your standard stone sword.

Answer (score 9):

Hitting them while backing up is pretty effective. Just hold your left mouse button button down with your chrosshairs pointed at the mob. When it turns red (indicating it took damage), immediately back up. Repeat until the zombie is dead.

Comment: yeah this jousting method is usually the best you can hope for, without using a bow or any traps.

Comment: sadly it's less than successful in multiplayer, probably due to the latency

Comment: that's kinda what i've been doing, but they aaaallllways seem to get me :D even if they are behind a block and can't pass through.. one would imagine to be safe but hey always hit you at least once.. thanks

Comment: Holding down the attack button no longer works—if you don't hit something it "unpushes" the button. To achieve the same effect now requires furious clicking.

Answer (score 2):

Build a trap!  That way you don't even have to waste materials in producing swords, etc.  The simplest is to dig a pit 3-4 blocks deep and at least 2x2 wide, and plant some cacti in it.  Put the pit between you and the zombie and watch it fall inside and eventually die.

Better traps, such as most water traps, can actually kill the zombie and deliver the dropped goods outside to you.  There are many videos on youtube that demonstrate how to build one, (such as this one:

)

Comment: Traps are good to have around your base and at key areas, but don't really help you out too much when you encounter a wandering monster. :)

Answer (score 1):

Armour!

Armour really helps prevent damage.  A full undamaged set of armour will prevent all damage to your health for the next hit.

Also, a three high wall with a hole in in helps keep them away while you hit them.

Answer (score 1):

Mob pathfinding is really dumb, and you can use this to your advantage. Partially hide yourself behind a corner, a tree, etc. The zombie will get stopped by the blocks, and you can hit him repeatedly until he dies.

Also - unlike spiders, which jump, or skeletons, which shoot, zombies just walk forward. If you time it right, you can strike them with your sword without getting hit at all.

Comment: Mob pathfinding has been improved, so this doesn't work as well anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Build a one block wide passage so one zombies could go in at a time. As a bonus, build a really good trap that doesn't involve lava, so the zombies could just walk right into it and end up committing suicide because they only have one target, you. For example, drown them! =)